# Show that this is an infinite orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

I am trying to be advance in linear algebra but I dont have enough resources. I tried to solve this question but I couldn't.

Let V be the real inner product space of the real valued functions on the interval $−1≤t≤1$ with inner product
$$
<f\mid g>= \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx.
$$

Suppose that
$f_n(x)=\sqrt2{\cos|2πnx|}$ and
$g_n(x)=\sqrt2{\sin|2πnx|}$. Show that $(1,f_1,g_1,f_2,g_2,…)$ is a infinite orthonormal set.

Comment: Try to format your question using MathJax.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, there's a few things you should know: The title of your post should describe the question, which yours does not. Mathematical expressions should be formatted using mathjax, as is [explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360). Finally, it would help if you could expand on the fact that you weren't able to solve the question. Do you understand the question? If so, then where did you run into trouble?

Comment: The usual notation for inner product is not a slash as you have it. I've seen $<f,g>$ for inner product...

Comment: What have you tried ?